# Hello! Started learning Java recently and having trouble repeating program instructions

Tags: java

I am new to Java and programming outside of VB in general and I am looking for some basic help.
I wrote the following code below and I want the program to repeat until the user types stop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lame
{
     public static void main (String args[])
     {
          System.out.println("Welcome to robo lame tester 1.1, is your name Connor? Yes or no?");
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String sweg = input.nextLine();
          if (sweg.equals("Yes"))
               System.out.println("You are lame");
          else 
               System.out.println("You passed, you aren't lame");
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to use a loop to repeat things until you get the desired input.

Comment: Here is a java [loop tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typed this in real quick... but it should do what you ask. So I added a while true that would make it loop forever. The while(condition) statement will loop until condition is given a false statement. The other way to leave would be to break the loop with the break statement or the return statement (as I did in there). break will make you leave the loop and return will make you leave the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lame {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        while(true) {
         System.out.println("Welcome to robo lame tester 1.1, is your name Connor? Yes or no?");
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         String sweg = input.nextLine();
         if(sweg.equals("stop"))
             return;
         if (sweg.equals("Yes"))
              System.out.println("You are lame");
         else 
              System.out.println("You passed, you aren't lame");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same scanner could be used throughout the whole loop, I believe? :)

Comment: Oh, yea of course it could. But I wrote this like really, really fast. There's a couple things that could be better in there :p We could mention the case sensitivity of the inputs. It would also be better code to put a condition in the while instead of true and have it go to false in the if(sweg.equals("stop")).

Comment: yep, `if (sweg.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))` or maybe more optimally (to prevent lowercasing the already lowercased "stop"): `if sweg.toLowerCase.equals("stop")`

Answer (score 0):

Insert it in a loop, as this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lame {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        String sweg = "";
        do {
            System.out
                    .println( "Welcome to robo lame tester 1.1, is your name Connor? Yes or no?" );
            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
            sweg = input.nextLine();
            if ( sweg.equalsIgnoreCase( "Yes" ) ) {
                System.out.println( "You are lame" );
            } else if ( sweg.equalsIgnoreCase( "no" ) ) {
                System.out.println( "You passed, you aren't lame" );
            }
        } while ( !sweg.equalsIgnoreCase( "stop" ) );
        System.out.println( "Bye!" );
    }
}
```

### Adendum

Class names begin with a capital by convention in Java. String's equalsIgnoreCase is recommended for user input, so they don't need to maintain the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String sweg = null;
while(!((sweg =input.nextLine()).equals("stop"))){
    System.out.println("you are lame");
}
```